# How to approximate a probability density function using its moments?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, laplace-transform, moment-generating-functions, moment-problem

I have an unknown probability density function(pdf) with support on the real line and I can compute numerically all its moments. 
How can I then approximate this pdf using any technique/algorithm?

I have read that this problem is sometimes called the 'Hamburger moment problem' and that Laplace transforms could help.

Thanks!
Maria

Answer (score 1):

A good approximation is the set of [Pearson distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_distribution). They allow you to include information of both kurtosis and skewness. Moreover, you can use them even when the support is not the whole real line